# Repeat Column Headers In Grouped Kable

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I have a dataframe:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(inst = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), 
         year_1_type1 = c(1,5,3,8,7,9,4), 
         year_2_type1 = c(5,7,8,3,5,2,6), 
         year_1_type2 = c(1,5,3,8,7,9,4), 
         year_2_type2 = c(5,7,8,3,5,2,6))
```

and I'm trying to create a grouped kable output with repeated headers. You'll see that I have a `header_above` feature that groups by Type to avoid confusion but it's not allowing me to repeat year_1 and year_2. I Tried adding `col.names` and got the error

```
Error in round(x[, j], digits[j]) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function

df1  %>%
  kbl(caption = '<b>Table 5</b>-Comparison of Types and Years', align='l',  col.names = "inst", "year 1", "year 2", "year 1", "year 2") %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = T, html_font = "Arial Narrow") %>% 
  kable_styling() %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Type 1" = 2, 
                     "Type 2"=2), align = "l")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error isn't related to grouping headers, you have a typo in the call to `kbl`:

```r
  kbl(..., col.names = "inst", "year 1", "year 2", "year 1", "year 2") %>%
#                     ^^^ missing a c( to start the vector, and a closing )
```

Try this:

```r
df1  %>%
  kbl(caption = '<b>Table 5</b>-Comparison of Types and Years', align='l',  
      col.names = c("inst", "year 1", "year 2", "year 1", "year 2")) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = T, html_font = "Arial Narrow") %>% 
  kable_styling() %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Type 1" = 2, "Type 2"=2), align = "l")
```

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh! thank you for your assistance!

Comment: One trick to finding this was removing calls in the `%>%`-pipe one by one to confirm in which function the error was emitting. In this case, it narrows down to the first, and casual inspection hinted that the `col.names` should likely be a vector but was not. Debugging R can be difficult at times, tis good to work on these techniques :-)